# JSP/ JQuery Mobile session time out issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Server Side : JSP/Servlets

Client Side Javascript Mobile Framework: JQuery Mobile

Problem: After session time out, when i am clicking on any of the hyperlinks on the present page, JQuery mobile is displaying the "Error Loading  Page" message instead of migration to the page specified where the session check will happen and display session time out message.
On javascript console "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) " is being displayed. Without Jquery mobile the entire thing works fine. How can i overcome this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Now don't blame jQuery Mobile for it. When the service request fails it will go to the function that you specified when the service call fails.

So you need add the following line in your function which is called when the service call fails

```
function serviceCallFailed(){
//Assuming that your login page's name is loginpage.html
 $.mobile.changePage('loginpage.html');
}
```

Comment: thanks for the solution ! Yes there is no reason to blame jquery mobile because there was Null pointer exception in the jsp itself which caused to send back the error code 500.